# When installing new modules through macports, can I skip some dependent modules (I have already)?

Tags: macports

Can I skip some large modules already installed in my system? If I can, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short:** No.

**Long**: You can ignore dependencies but then your software will probably not run.

The philosophy of Macports is not to interfere or depend on the system.

For example:
A python-applications depends on python from Macports.

Comment: Thanks for answering this long ignored question. Can I configure it to depend on some modules which are already installed elsewhere in my system?

Comment: You could do that when creating Portfiles (receipes) but this is very bad style (for this philosphy). Some Ports do rely on the system because it is not technically possible otherwise. The idea of MacPorts is to be one "standalone" system.

Comment: Philipp is quite correct, MacPorts is it's own tree of code. Simple system maintenance ( every morning port sync && port outdated; port upgrade outdated) and it's fine